# Эмуляция CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, что-то очень простое

Tags: curl, php

Доброго. Пятничная тема по поводу выноса мозгов.

```
//вот такая штука в выполняемом файле
//Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.. строка такая то..

//вот эта самая строка
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Собственно, конечно, можно переписать заголовки к документу, но оно работать не будет. Еще можно погуглить готовую функцию по эмуляции данного действа, и тут то ли у меня лыжи не едут, то ли едут, но не лыжи, а мозги.

Вопрос: может ли кто написать КОД (функцию + обращение, что угодно), который затрагивает только эту команду? Не это + что-то еще, а код, который заменял конкретно эту строку?

P.S. В Инете есть решения конкретных задач, но вот так, чтобы 1 строку, - этого нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы очень качественно цитируете сообщения об ошибке ;-)
Но ничего страшного, мы же программисты! Включаем телепат-мод........... Done!

Вангую, что полное сообщение звучало наподобие такого:

> Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in

Собственно, в нем уже указано, что следует сделать: отключить safe_mode или убрать директиву open_basedir.

Comment: Эх.. надеялся, что есть другое решение. Но все же спасибо, начну с техподдержки, и изменения safe_mode.